# Declare table variable with columns as mush as row in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with id in database. I want to declare table variable with columns as much as id count in the id table(now its 16, but in future it will be more).

[image]

The columns name must be the id name.

[image]

I tried to use table_cursor, and dynamic query with creating table variable. And its worked, but in the future its called a lot of troubles. Does it possible to create table variable without dynamic query?

Comment: What troubles do you mean? you can create a view and use pivot.

Comment: SQL Servers has `PIVOT`. But how do you find the values, why should the _0 value be 725 and not 'planned_stop'?

Comment: One way or another it is not possible to do this without a dynamic query if the `id`s are variable; T-SQL really wants result sets to have a static shape. Even with `PIVOT` / `UNPIVOT` you are required to list the possible values. You are typically much better off changing/extending client code so this awkward reshaping isn't necessary in the first place.

Comment: @jarlh _0 this column will be id for operation 0. And value 725 is the time value of my 0 operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TempTable
CREATE TABLE TempTable (Id INT IDENTITY,
                        Status_name varchar(30),
                        [Count] INT
                        )
INSERT INTO TempTable(Status_name,[Count])
SELECT 'in_Work'    , 28 UNION ALL
SELECT 'in_reserve' , 44 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned_Stop'   , 78 UNION ALL
SELECT '_empty' , 55 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Waiting'    , 43 

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @DynamicColumn nvarchar(max),
        @MaxDynamicColumn nvarchar(max)

SELECT @DynamicColumn = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT', '+QUOTENAME(CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM TempTable  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 

SELECT @MaxDynamicColumn = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT', '+'MAX('+QUOTENAME(CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)))+') AS '+QUOTENAME('_'+CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM TempTable  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 

SET @Sql='SELECT  '+ @MaxDynamicColumn+'
            FROM
            (
            SELECT *
            FROM TempTable o
            )AS src
            PIVOT 
            (
            MAX([Count]) FOR [Id] IN ('+@DynamicColumn+')
            ) AS Pvt
            '
EXEC (@Sql)
PRINT @Sql
```